# Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(object)); returning an empty object?

Tags: c#, json

I am attempting to write the contents of an object to the console using Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(object));
but it only writes a {} - which I assume is an empty JSON file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
namespace PetShopPart1
{

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //DogLeash dogLeash = new DogLeash();
            //dogLeash.Quantity = 0;
            //dogLeash.Material = "0";
            //dogLeash.LengthInches = 0;


            DogLeash dogLeash = new DogLeash
            {
                Quantity = 1,
                Material = "0",
                LengthInches = 0,
            };
            
            string userInput = "0";

            while (userInput != "exit")
            {
        
                if (userInput == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many leashes would you like?\n");
                    dogLeash.Quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("What Material would you like your leash(es) to be made of.\n");
                    dogLeash.Material = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("And how many inches would you like your leash to be?\n");
                    dogLeash.LengthInches = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dogLeash));
                
                
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to add an item.\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Type Exit to Quit.\n");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Dogleash.cs:

```cs
using System;

namespace PetShopPart1
{
    class DogLeash : Product
    {
        public int LengthInches;
        public string Material;
    }
}
```

Product.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PetShopPart1
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name;
        public decimal Price;
        public int Quantity = 0;
        public string Description;
    }
}
```

[image: Console Output]

Comment: You haven't shown us `Dogleash`, which makes it really hard to help. We don't need any user input or anything - just provide a *minimal* but complete program. (Just instantiate a Dogleash with hard-coded values and serialize it - but do show us *all* the code.)

Comment: Looking at your `Product` class, it only has fields in it, where by default the serializer will only serialize properties.  I assume this is the same for `Dogleash`.

Comment: This is *still* far from minimal, although at least it's complete. (Please pay attention to formatting when posting though - use the preview, and don't post it until it's in a form that you'd be happy to read it in.) But fundamentally, Matthew's right: you don't have any properties.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys! I apologize for the poor post, I just started a bootcamp and am very new to all of this. I'll be more attentive in the future. Thanks again for the instruction! - Aaron Sierp

Answer (score 2):

In case it's not clear from the comments on your question,

```
public int LengthInches;
```

is a *field*

```
public int LengthInches {get; set;}
```

is a *property* - and `JsonSerializer` only serializes properties *by default*.

Comment: This "JsonSerializer only serializes properties" is a bit misleading. You can set IncludeFields in the JsonSerializerOptions - the above comments are pointing this out correctly by refering to "by default".

Comment: @Postlagerkarte Reasonable callout. I've updated my answer.